# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline' While Reading from File

Tags: python

I run this code:

```
file=open(filename, 'r')

line=filename.readline()
totallines=0
total=0
while line != "":
    amount=float(line)
    print(format(amount, '.2f'))
    line=filename.readline()
    totallines+=1
    total+=amount
avg=total/totallines
print("The average of the numbers is", format(avg, '.2f'))
```

and it gives me this error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'**

I dont understand what Im doing wrong?

Comment: `filename` is a string. you should do `file.readline()`

Answer (score 3):

You are calling **filename** which is a string instead of **file** in here

```
file=open(filename, 'r')
line=filename.readline()
```

Should be **line=file.readline()**

In order to improve the code I suggest you use **with** and **as** which is *faster* in execution as well besides being *more readable*:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file
line=file.readline()
```